# Selenium Grid 4 Issue getting Test Node URL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

In Selenium Grid 3 (hosted On-Prem) we were able to get the Test Node url using a Get Request like "http://10.10.10.10:4444/grid/api/testsession?session=9f7d1d2bbc26720fe69e869ae9ef1c56" which would return the Node url.

We have since migrated to Selenium Grid 4 which is now Dockerised and hosted on K8s. The issue is when we try and do the same request to the new site we get an "Unknown Command" error with messages:

> "*unable to find handler (get)*"

or

> "*Cannot call non W3C Standard command while in W3C mode*".

We have tried the below calls as suggested online but no luck with any

- https://selenium-hub.com/grid/api/testsession?session=765d091f20bfa716bfa485889ccc7b12
- https://selenium-hub.com/wd/hub/grid/api/testsession?session=765d091f20bfa716bfa485889ccc7b12
- https://selenium-hub.com/wd/hub/testsession?session=765d091f20bfa716bfa485889ccc7b12
- https://selenium-hub.com/wd/hub/testsession/session=765d091f20bfa716bfa485889ccc7b12
- https://selenium-hub.com/wd/hub/testsession/765d091f20bfa716bfa485889ccc7b12
- https://selenium-hub.com/wd/hub/sessions

Have also tried with the port but it really doesn't like that, request won't even be made.

Would anyone know if we can make Requests to Selenium Grid 4 to get Test Node Url's and possible requests to try?

Answer (score 0):

Now you can get `/status` endpoint of your hub. It will return you a JSON object.

So you will just parse what you need. Find the example output here https://ctxt.io/2/AACQ95aVFA for sessionId = `2eecded19bcff7aea960a598b6628aed`

Comment: when you try and parse the json to get the uri based off sessionId we just get error message when try to get the value within the slots section "cannot access child value on newtownsoft.json.linq.value". Have tried many ways adding null checks without any luck. Is there specific code for this or a way to return only the node section based on sessionId?

Comment: Was able to use https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/advanced_features/graphql_support/#query-to-get-session-information-for-a-given-session endpoints here. This specific endpoint gives the uri back https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/advanced_features/graphql_support/#query-to-get-session-information-for-a-given-session